# How can I use javascript to disable all links on page except those with a particular class

Tags: javascript, wordpress

sorry I am new to javascript but i'm working on a wordpress website and have to disable all the links on the home page from being clickable except the links with a particular class e.g. 'clickable'. As long as the link has that class, it becomes clickable.

I have been tweeking the below script but  do not know how to introduce the class comparism, can anyone help me with this?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.tag === links.tag) {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.addEventListener('contextmenu', 
                event => event.preventDefault());
                el_down.innerHTML = "Right click disabled";
            }
        });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I never downvote a newcomer. I added a  helperlink, as your question is incomplete to allow us to answer it. That's also probably the reason of the unknown downvote : there are almost 3 million questions here just in JS and 3/4 are all badly asked,  generally because newcomers rarely read the advice pages that have been patiently brought to their attention. After a while your question will probably be deleted from the server because it takes up unnecessary space, by the fact that it does not bring any content likely to help the community. You can then recover these handicap points.

Answer (score 0):

This did it:

```
  document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // filter out clicks on any other elements
  if (event.target.nodeName == 'A' && event.target.getAttribute('aria-disabled') == 'true') {
  console.log("True")
  }
  else {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', 
  event => event.preventDefault());
  el_down.innerHTML = "Right click disabled";
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).